# PHP: Best way to forward a user to a different URL dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex

I'm helping put together a site that's going to host content for different regions on the same domain. So example:

www.example.com/us/
www.example.com/uk/
www.example.com/fr/
etc.

I have a system in place that asks the user which site they want to view (and then stores their preference in a cookie). My question is: If they visit a URL (e.g.: www.example.com/us/contact.php) and their preference cookie says /fr/, how do I best forward them to www.example.com/fr/contact.php?

The system can read what site region they're on and what their cookie says. So the information we would know would be: Site: US and Cookie: FR.

I was thinking of using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and using regex to get "contact.php" from the URL. Then using `header("Location: [url]");`, but I understand that `Location` doesn't work if any text has already been passed to the browser... which creates all sorts of problems.

**Edit:**
Here's some code to explain the problem more clearly:

```
<?php
// Get variable contents for $cookieRegion and $siteRegion
if($cookieRegion != '') { // If Cookie has been previous set
    if($cookieRegion != $siteRegion) { // If Cookie pref clashes with site URL
       // Forward to correct URL
    }
}
else { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Display modal window asking user preference
        });
    </script>        
<?php } ?>
```

So the `<script>` tag would be placed before the document start... not a good idea!

What's the best way to get around this problem?

Or, is there a better way of handling the whole problem that I could implement instead?

Comment: If you place the functionality for the language detection before any output has been sent -- *e.g.* before your template is rendered, or before `<!DOCTYPE ...><html xmlns="...">...` if you're using a flat script (not MVC) -- you can still send the location and then either use `exit()`, to stop any unnecessary operations to be executed, or not.

Comment: @jwandborg, The problem is that if the Cookie hasn't been set, I want to run some Javascript after the page has loaded, and I can't put the necessary JS (from the "else") before the document has loaded... :-/

Comment: You can't redirect the user to the correct page in the same pageload as you are asking for a language, You have to assume that they are speaking english first and then bring up a dialogue. This code could exist anywhere in the document, but the `header()` statement has to be executed before any output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: @vartec, You should probably read the entire question before you comment. You should also probably read the contents of the links you post. I'm one of the editors on that question who helped construct the answer. Here, you'll need this: `*facepalm*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
// Use this to open modal window.
$wrongRegion = FALSE;

// if there is a cookie...
if (isset($_COOKIE['region']))
{
    // I am using preg_match to ensure we are getting right parameters...
    // Sorry I am not good with Regex. You can set a better patern.
    preg_match("#/(.*?)/(.*?)\.php#is", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $m);

    // Okay! $m[1][0] is the region code on the uri. lets check if its same with cookie
    if ($_COOKIE['region'] != $m[1][0])
        $wrongRegion = TRUE;
}

....... (codes goes here)

// to where you put the modal window code:

if ($wrongRegion == TRUE)
{
    // put the modal window code.
}
```

so you can add a check to preg_match. It prevents to execute rest of the code.

Comment: How should I do "proper localization"? Also, what does this mean: "Grab the region and to the rest of the codes using this region"? Thanks.

Comment: Ohh never mind. I though you are trying to redirect page. even though it was wrong. I deleted it. so nevermind. but code should work.

Comment: This answers my question, but I am concerned about readability :-/ I can't think of another way around the problem, though!

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code, or some equivalent code before ANY HTML or linebreaks.

```
<?php
# This will split the request URI into an array with all the components between slashes in the URI
$request_parameters = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']);

# Now, hopefully $request_parameters[1] contains the language abbreviation/code
if ( $request_parameters[1] != $cookieLanguage ) {
    # Replace the erroneous language with the language saved in the cookie, 
    # reassemble the URI and send the client to the correct location
    $request_parameters[1] = $cookieLanguage;
    header('Location: ' . implode('/', $request_parameters);
}
```

If there is not any cookie set

1. Show the default page *e.g.* `/en-US/contact/`
2. Let the client choose language

   - If and when the client chooses a language; set the language cookie and reload the page.

Comment: This is filled with useful ideas, but it doesn't actually solve my problem.

Comment: It's a tricky question, it's Friday and I haven't had enough sleep tonight, did you see my comment on your post? I'm basically thinking what Gokhan Ozturk posted.

Comment: No problems. I gave you a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Read the cookie first, then parse where the user wants to go (contact.php), then redirect it with Location: before sending output, so at the beginning of index.php

Comment: That makes sense, but the problem is that if the Cookie hasn't been set, I want to run some Javascript after the page has loaded (creating a modal window asking the user to set their preference). This would essentially be the "else" of the "if cookie is set", and I can't put the necessary JS (from the "else") before the beginning of the document... :-/

Comment: Let the user make the decision, and reload it :3. `location.reload()` or something

Comment: That actually doesn't solve the problem in any way. On their return visit, I still want to check the cookie for their preference instead of nagging them.

Comment: What I meant was, let the user make a decision, store the cookie via javascript, reload the page and off they go (:

Comment: And when they return a month later, go a URL from a different region, what do you suggest happens?

Comment: Assuming the cookie doesn't exist, you might just ask them to decide again. Small chance users will be annoyed to do it once in a month.

Comment: The cookie still exists... what then?

Comment: Oh from a different region... Just let them re-choose, its the only thing you could do. You could never know it is the same user, only when it logs in with an account.

Comment: Cookie says: FR. URL says: US. What then?

Comment: That depends on what YOU want to do, you can either choose to stick to the region specified by the cookie, or by the URL. Your call.

Comment: I want to direct the user to the site based on their preferences... that's the _whole point_ of storing it in a cookie. Why else would I do that?

Comment: I'm trying to explain why your solution doesn't work. That is completely _on_ topic.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting while trying to help you :'). We don't understand each other.

Comment: I've done my absolute best to explain why you're not answering my question. I'm not sure what else I could do to help you improve your answer.

Comment: Your answer isn't remotely helpful to my question. If you edit it, so that it is, I will change my vote. That's how this site works.

Comment: Did you just get a friend to go and downvote two of my answers on other questions or something? That's not how things are done here.

Comment: @Guus: Try not to take down-votes personally. It's an indication of how an answer fits to the question, not a personal affront. Certainly don't make wide-sweeping ultimatums about downvoting regardless of content value - that's not the community we want to foster here. Retribution is a pointless tactic when trying to exchange information.

I recommend considering Django's original question in the context provided by your discussion here and determine if an edited answer would fit better.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually very simple.

At the beginning of your script (before any html.. especially the  tag!) do something along these lines:

```
 <?

 if $locationCookie == 'fr') {

 header("Location: /fr");

 //or alternatively
 //header("Location: /fr/contact.php");

 }

 //also, let's say they are on the us/contact.php page and you want them to go to the fr/contact.php page

 header('Location: ../'.$language_cookie.'/contact.php');

 ?>
```

What this will do is redirect the user to the SAME PAGE they are currently on, but will have the $_GET variable of language equal to fr. Then, in your page you should check for this variable and make the proper changes accordingly.

Comment: Or even better: `header("Location: ?language=" . $locationCookie)` for a more dynamic redirection.

Comment: The OP does not use the GET parameter but uses a URI path *("folder")* to determine the language.

Comment: This isn't really solving the problem at all, come to think of it.

Comment: You've just explained to me how to use `Location`. I'm afraid I already know that, the problem is the logic of the modal window. Please see _my_ edit :)